# vscode react+typescript + mocha: breakpoints not hit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mocha.js, visual-studio-code, breakpoints

I am trying for many days now to have typescript breakpoints hit in my mocha tests with no success. They keep getting hit in the .js files, not the typescript source files. I am using vscode 1.9.1. I have already asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43412760/vscode-react-typescript-mocha-breakpoints-stop-in-js-files) with yet no answer yet. I am been reading several similar issues here on stackoverflow and on google. No solution has worked for me.

Here is a screenshot of the breakpoint been hit in the `.js file`, not the typescript:

[image]

This file is a read-only file which seems to be produced by mocha at run-time. The strange thing here is that I see `sourcemaps characters` inserted at the end of the .js file although in my `tsconfig.json` (below) I have the option `"sourceMap": true` which means that sourcemaps are a separate file.

I suspect this is the cause of my problem. I have been pulling my hair for many days, looking for a solution all over internet. It seems that many people face the same problem. Sure there must someone who has been able to debug mocha + typescript files .

**P.S**

This is React + Typescript application. In a React-Native application I am developping, there my typescript mocha test files have their breakpoints hit.

1. here is my tsconfig.json:

[image]

I have tried various combinations (`sourceMaps:true`, removing sourceRoot...etc)

2. Here is my lauchn.json

[image]

Comment: you can try look through the issues on vscode repository, maybe there will be something helpful: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues , here is a similar one: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3144